# What would be the consequences, as an EU citizen, of overstaying by about a week the basic 3 months stay in Denmark?

Tags: immigration, eu, denmark

I am currently in Denmark, as an EU citizen, still within my 3-month stay. What would be the consequences if I overstayed that 90-day window for about a week before leaving?

I am about to move to the UK, and my UK visa starts just about a week after the end of the three months I'm allowed to be in Denmark without a residence certificate. I don't really have anywhere to go until I can move to the UK. What do I effectively risk by staying that additional week? Would it fuck up my UK visa status in some way?

I could apply for a residence certificate with "sufficient funds" reasons, since I definitely have sufficient funds for staying less than a week, but would it even be worth it since processing times for those are, like, 60 days apparently?

The alternative would be to fly back to my home country and getting a hotel or something for the week before my visa starts, which would be incredibly expensive and something I'm trying to avoid (but of course, if it's the only course of action it's what I'll do).

Comment: Would it even be worth it?  The application is free of charge and the processing time is 0-30 days (https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Residence-as-a-Nordic-citizen-or-EU-or-EEA-citizen/EU-Self-support). I'd guess closer to zero days in your case.  I suspect that the potential consequences are fairly minor, but there is likely to be a fine.  Perhaps it's not likely to be applied to someone leaving after 14 weeks, but if it is, well, it's certainly going to cost more than submitting an application.

Comment: If they found you out, they could ask you to leave by a specific date (which they may drop since you are leaving anyway). Any possible fine would be based on how a danish citizen would be fined if they failed any registration requirements.